# How to decode many words in a sequence?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I am trying to randomize some words from a list. The idea is that each letter of the word randomizes until it forms the word and then skips to the next word. Basically decoding the a list of words. Each one has an index and animating the index switches the element in the list. The problem is that it only works whenever the frame starts from zero again.

This is an example:
[image]

See node tree:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks :D

Comment: Have you considered making a python script node for this?  Probably easier in the long run...

Comment: @Kirbinator, I don't have the technical knowledge to do that.

Comment: Here is an example that I did which hopefully is what you're looking to achieve: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=E4NGwqEj" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/E4NGwqEj/)

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks for your help, much appreciated. :) Although what I am looking for is to first reveal a word and then the second substituting the first and so on rather than completing a phrase. I am trying to understand your file and couldn't, as it seems too complex, in order to maybe use it for inspiration. Cheers

Comment: I think I need a loop but haven't figured out how to do it... :/