# Number changing animation with animation nodes?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

[image]How to make number changing animation with animation nodes pleae?

Answer (score 1):

First we have to make two lists of texts. first list containing 5 copies of `14.5 260` and second list containing the modified text. Then we can use a switch node to switch between these two lists. The switching condition can be set using a sine node which produces flickering effect.

[image]

Here is the full node tree :

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is great! Simply out of words... Thank You so much Sir!  ALL THE BEST!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following the logic shown here you can eventually manage to do it as you like:

[How to decode many words in a sequence?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170010/how-to-decode-many-words-in-a-sequence)